# How to extract data from worksheet (Without headers) and add to bottom of csv file (Without opening it in excel, contains 3.6m+ lines)

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I am using a power pivot to create a pivot table with a data connection to a csv file with 3.6m+ rows of data and 230mb in size.

Everyday I add to this csv file by running a report in .xslx format (Report can only be ran in this format), I would like to use VBA to automate the daily process below if possible:

- Remove headers in the DailyReport.xslx workbook
- Save as DailyReport.csv
- Open Master.csv in notepad (Excel only opens the first 1048576 rows)
- Copy the data from Report.csv (Without headers in row 1)
- Paste data at the bottom of Master.csv
- Open PowerPivot.xlsb (Containing data connection to Master.csv)
- Refresh data connection and pivot tables to pull through new data

I have found a lot of VBA macros that can copy text into a CSV file but most either create a CSV file or write to it through excel which i cannot do due to row limit of 1048576 being surpassed.

I know how to select the data from my report and convert the file just not sure about handing text in .csv files without opening in excel through VBA.

```
Sub DataMerge()

'--------------------------------------------------
'- Title:    Data Merge                           -
'- Purpose:  Merge data (Daily report/Master csv) -
'--------------------------------------------------

' Set example path
Dim ExamplePath As String
ExamplePath = "C:\Exmaple\Path\"

' Set report as variable
Dim rwb As Workbook
Workbooks.Open Filename:=ExamplePath & "Report.xlsx"
Set rwb = Application.Workbooks("Report.xlsx")

' Convert report to csv and set as variable
rwb.SaveAs Filename:=ExamplePath & "Report.csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
Dim rcsv As Workbook
Set rcsv = Application.Workbooks("Report.csv")

' Find range and copy data
Dim LastRow As Integer
LastRow = rcsv.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Rows.Count
rcsv.Sheets(1).Range("A2:A" & LastRow).Copy

' Open master csv file as text and paste selection at the bottom of the file and save
'#######################
'Put requested code here
'#######################

' Close report.csv and open file containing data connection
Workbooks("Report.csv").Close SaveChanges:=False
Dim ppwb As Workbook
Workbooks.Open Filename:=ExamplePath & "PowerPivot.xlsb"
Set ppwb = Application.Workbooks("PowerPivot.xlsb")

' Set as variable and refresh
ppwb.RefreshAll ' When refreshed, excel asks to locate text import file.
' Can this be specified through VBA so user does not need to select file?

ppwb.Close SaveChanges:=True

End Sub
```

Please also see above comment at the end of my code, I would like a way to specify which text file to import (.csv) as it asks the user but it will be the save master file every time, so seems a bit of a waste to ask every time for something that never changes.

I spotted this code from another StackOverflow answer which could be used as part for the macro:

```
Sub ReadCSV()
    Dim MyString As String
    Open "C:\path\text.csv" For Input As #1 ' Open file for input. 
    Do While Not EOF(1) ' Loop until end of file.
        Line Input #1, MyString ' Read a line into variable
        Debug.Print MyString ' Print data to the Immediate window.
    Loop
    Close #1 ' Close file.

End Sub
```

Source: [Manipulate/copy .CSV data, without opening the file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10734631/manipulate-copy-csv-data-without-opening-the-file)

As I think this will open the file as text and not as an excel file? (Correct me if I am wrong). I just do not know how to manipulate the text to do what i need to do in my daily procedure mentioned at the beginning of my question.

I will greatly appreciate any help with this problem, thanks in advance!

Comment: You *want* a procedure that goes `Open filepath For Append As #NotHardCodedFileHandle` where `NotHardCodedFileHandle` is a local variable assigned to the return value of `FreeFile`, ...but IMO what you *need* is to have these records in an actual database.

Comment: An actual database would be ideal but the company I work for does not have this software and will not be looking to get it.I was thinking of building a database outside of work and showing the benefits to my employer so they could see this would be beneficial but I do not actually know how to use databases such as MS Access because I have never had to use it before.